# Alter table error adding 2 columns

Tags: postgresql

Database:POSTGRESQL

I have a table location_type with 2 columns id,name. I want to delete column name and add 2 other columns:county,city. However I get error and I can't figure out why. 
This is what I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE location_type
DROP COLUMN name;

ALTER TABLE location_type
ADD (county character varying(255) NOT NULL,
     city character varying(255) NOT NULL);
```

Maybe someone can see what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco syntax error at or near "("

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this [[Doc]](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE location_type
    ADD county character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    ADD city character varying(255) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please link to current manual unless you *need* to reference outdated documentation. [Consider this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168).

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I'll consider it next time.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

```
ALTER TABLE location_type DROP COLUMN name;
ALTER TABLE location_type ADD county character varying(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE location_type ADD city character varying(255) NOT NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE location_type 
    DROP COLUMN name,
    ADD county character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    ADD city character varying(255) NOT NULL;
```

Check [manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Marco and @Erkan already cleared up:

If your table is populated already (has rows), you cannot add columns with a `NOT NULL` without a `DEFAULT` clause. New rows are added with `NULL` values unless you provide a different `DEFAULT` - thus contradicting the constraint.

In older versions of PostgreSQL (before version 8.0) you could not use the `DEFAULT` clause with new columns. You had to add the column, populate it and **then** set it `NOT NULL`.

Comment: yeah I knew about this already so this was not a problem. +1 though for trying to help